# Wordpress no enlaza a single.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

Hola estaba transformando mi html a wordpress y todo bien en mi pagina index.php practicamente tengo una pagina normal estatica no hace nada, luego en la pagina page.php tengo mi blog con las entadas y todo normal, pero cuando presiono una entrada no me redirige a la pagina single.php sino que se queda en page.php

```html
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <section class="add-flex reservation-section" id="uno">
  <div class="center-text add-padding">
    <h1 class="alex-brush"><span class="custom-font"><img src=" <?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/Nuestra.png" alt=""></span><br /> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
    <p> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();  ?>">Seguir leyendo</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/Fundadora-1-.jpg" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300"/>
    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' );?>/img/Fundadora-2.jpg" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="300"/>
  </div>
</section>
<hr> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No entiendo qué quieres decir con que no te redirige a `single.php`

Comment: supuestamente al dar click en una entrada deberia mandarte a la pagina single.php en donde esta el contenido de la entrada para lograr eso hice un enlace y le agregue the_permalink(); pero no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo para lograr solucionarlo hay que notar que en una pagina de wordpress cualquier enlace te volvera a mandar a esa misma pagina asi que no puedes tener tus entradas en la pagina page.hph sino la forma correcta es tenerlos en la pagina index.php